# Insert data on a button click to ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have to make a textarea editable with ckeditor. A button is placed after the editor. If that button is clicked, I need to add an html code to the editor.
The code to load CK Editor is:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('mail_content');
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
                ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],
                // '/',
                ['Bold','Italic','Underline','StrikeThrough','-','Undo','Redo','-','Cut','Copy','Paste','Find','Replace','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Print'],
                // '/',
                ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
                ['Flash','TextColor','BGColor']
            ] ;
```

The button is

```
<button name="edit" id="edit" >edit</button>
```

Comment: please share the full js and html

Comment: Thr is nothing else written in the js

Comment: What html code do you need to add when you press "edit" button?

Comment: something like "<p>dsfds</p>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you need but if you need example look at this

```
<textarea name="mail_content" id="mail_content" rows="10" cols="80">
  This is a test
</textarea>
<button name="edit" id="edit" >edit</button>
<script>
$('#edit').click(function(){
  CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
      config.language = 'es';
      config.uiColor = '#F7B42C';
      config.height = 300;
      config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
            config.toolbar = [
                ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],
                // '/',
                ['Bold','Italic','Underline','StrikeThrough','-','Undo','Redo','-','Cut','Copy','Paste','Find','Replace','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Print'],
                // '/',
                ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
                ['Flash','TextColor','BGColor']
            ] ;

  };
  CKEDITOR.replace('mail_content');
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/reoh7j74/527

Answer (score 0):

Use [insertHtml](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-insertHtml):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.mail_content.insertHtml('<p>dsfds</p>');
```